# Design DB Structure for Mail Scheduling

Tags: database, db-structure

I need to design Database structure to mail report scheduling.
As far till now,I came forward with this design as follows:

```
    **ReportSchedule**
    - ScheduleId
     - ReportName
     - Subject
     - To
     - UserId
     - Body
     - Remarks

**ScheduleDaily**

 - Id
 - ScheduleId
 - StartDate
 - EndDate
 - SendTime

**ScheduleWeekly**

 - Id
 - ScheduleId
 - StartDate
 - EndDate
 - SendTime
 - DayOfWeek

**ScheduleMonthly**

 - Id
 - ScheduleId
 - StartDate
 - EndDate
 - SendTime
 - MonthOfYear
 - DayOfWeek

..................
```

I am not satisfied with this design and I need single table which covers all parameters (probably which includes reccurence rule).
Kindly suggest!!

Comment: What are the tables' relations? Is `ScheduleId` a FK to the `ReportSchedule` table? Does a `ReportSchedule` have multiple daily/weekly/monthly schedules?

Comment: ScheduleId is PK to Report Schedule.
Yes,ReportSchedule can have multiple schedules

Comment: I'm referring to the `ScheduleId` column _in the other tables_, obvously. And you'll have to describe your application logic a little more. Give some example data that cover all cases.

Comment: ScheduleId is FK to other tables.
Example: A user need to send report named ABC on every Monday and Thursday at 3:00PM

Comment: So that would be two rows in the `ScheduleDaily` table with a `ScheduleId` of `ABC`. Right? Got it.

Comment: Yes actually but I want the design that does not need 2 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Normalizing

As a first step, I see that most of the columns in the `Schedule*` tables are common. So you could move them in a `ScheduleCommon` table. But leave an `id` column behind, which will be the PK of the remaining tables *and a FK to the `ScheduleCommon` table at the same time*. That makes it an [IS-A relation](http://www.geomagas.gr/index.php/is-a-relations-in-relational-databases/).

The above step will actually add an extra table to your schema, but IMHO it's a necessary normalization step.

### 2. Globalizing the recurring rule

I'm thinking, you could replace the recurring rules in your tables with an `EveryHours` field and a `LastRun` one. That way you can determine if `LastRun`+`EveryHours` has come to past, and the job needs to run again (and update the `LastRun` field).

The above will eliminate the `Schedule*` tables, since those fields are common and can be moved to the `ScheduleCommon` table. That leaves you with only two tables.

### 3. Making it 1:1

*Provided that each report schedule has only one recurring schedule*, the relation of the two tables becomes 1:1 and the one can absorb the other. But I don't think this is the case. Let's examine the example you provided in the comments: *"send mail every Monday,Tuesday at 3:00PM of the month January"*. That's not one schedule but actually *two*:

```
ScheduleId  StartDate           EndDate             EveryHours
ABC         2014-01-06 3:00PM   2014-02-01 3:00PM   192
ABC         2014-01-07 3:00PM   2014-02-01 3:00PM   192
```

As you can see, you will have to maintain multiple schedules for the same task, which makes the relation 1:N.

Comment: sounds pretty cleaner but not understood  the 2nd point.Kindly elaborate with an example.

Comment: Well, having an `EveryHours` field enables you to schedule a task to run every X hours. If `EveryHours=24`, the event runs once a day. If `EveryHours=8` thrice a day and if `EveryHours=192` once a week.

Comment: If I add a schedule to send mail every Monday,Tuesday at 3:00PM of the month January then how the entries would be added??